# Errors related to python version added to error log when I start apache2

Tags: ubuntu, python, mod-python

When I start apache I am getting those errors:

```
[Tue Jun 14 02:28:58 2011] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.5', found '2.6.6'.
[Tue Jun 14 02:28:58 2011] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Tue Jun 14 02:28:58 2011] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.6/:/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload'.
[Tue Jun 14 02:28:58 2011] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Jun 14 02:28:58 2011] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Tue Jun 14 02:28:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I am using Ubuntu Server...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is Apache working?  That is, are these errors critical, or simply informative?  Have you installed Python and Apache from the same sources?

Comment: Same source? I used apt-get for it's setup. I used this: python, python-dev and libapache2-mod-python to install it.

Comment: ...and is it working?

Answer (score 1):

Build mod_python against the appropriate version of Python. Better yet, abandon the now-dead mod_python altogether and use mod_wsgi instead.

Comment: Great! How do I do that?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/91468/how-to-set-up-mod-wsgi-for-python-on-ubuntu

Comment: Cool I got rid of most of the errors. But I still get this one: [Tue Jun 14 03:37:02 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: That's a notice, not an error.